# Does Meteor's MergeBox duplicate common data between clients?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get an idea of how much memory the server will take up per client, and read that the MergeBox is a copy of the client's minimongo. Does the MergeBox keep a copy of all client's subscriptions, or just those that are different for that client? For example:

- Subscription 1: public data set that is the same for all clients
- Subscription 2: private data that only a particular client has access to.

Each of 10 clients subscribe to both Sub 1 and 2. Sub 1 is the same data for every client. Sub 1 and 2 each take 1MB. Is the server's MergeBox memory usage 20 MB or 11 MB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, 11 MB because the observers get reused. I'd recommend reading [this article](https://kadira.io/academy/improve-cpu-and-network-usage/) from the [kadira academy](https://kadira.io/academy/) blog. To quote:

> ... if you create multiple identical observers, Meteor won’t fetch the initial dataset from the DB for each observer. Instead, it reuses the data already fetched by the first observer.

I've also verified this by asking this exact question of the core devs in the past.

Comment: Even if Meteor didn't reused the observers, the RAM would be remain the same due to how Chrome V8 handles memory management. I think  the first subscription would be between 1 to 2 megabytes. Is the 11 megabytes estimation correct? I'm considering the range [1-2] because of internal information necessary to handle each client connection.